# how to for a correct html header using cgi.pm?

Tags: javascript, perl, cgi

I'm not familier with CGI.pm syntax.

I try to create html_header but I just can't get it working.
I need to have both http_equiv and the javascript. The header works fine without the -script part. What I'm doing wrong here?

```
print $cgi->start_html( 

    -head => meta({
        -http_equiv => "Refresh",
        -content =>"$viive;URL=http://192.168.1.42/saldo/index.cgi?varasto=$varasto"
    }),

    -title => 'Varasto '.$varasto, 
    -style => { -src => 'infotaulu.css' }

    -script => {
    -language => 'javascript',
    -src => '/sorttable.js'

);
```

Comment: The HTML generating part of CGI.pm is, frankly, horrible. I'd seriously consider using something like Template-Toolkit instead.

Answer (score 3):

Your problem is that you've missed the comma at the end of the `-style` parameter. Using this:

```
print $cgi->start_html(

    -head => $cgi->meta({
        -http_equiv => "Refresh",
        -content =>"$viive;URL=http://192.168.1.42/saldo/index.cgi?varasto=$varasto"
    }),

    -title => 'Varasto '.$varasto,
    -style => { -src => 'infotaulu.css' },

    -script => {
    -language => 'javascript',
    -src => '/sorttable.js'
    }
);
```

Gives me this output:

```
<!DOCTYPE html
    PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
     "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en-US" xml:lang="en-US">
<head>
<title>Varasto varasto</title>
<meta http-equiv="Refresh" content="viive;URL=http://192.168.1.42/saldo/index.cgi?varasto=varasto" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="infotaulu.css" />
<script src="/sorttable.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
</head>
<body>
```

I think that's what you want.

**However** I really think you should rethink your approach. Using the HTML-generation functions in CGI.pm is a terrible idea. You'll end up with a horrible unmaintainable mess of code. Please consider using a [templating system](http://tt2.org/) instead.

Comment: Thank you! Such a small mistake, but since the enviroment I'm using is what it is, I just couldn't find the mistake. Thanks!

Comment: Well, your missing comma was a small mistake, certainly. But using the HTML generation functions from CGI.pm is a **much** bigger mistake :-)